# ManagedAttribute mgAttr =context.getObjectByName("ManagedAttribute.class", <Test10>")

Tags: sailpoint

While executing the above  IIQ API it is throwing the error _Name not found and could not execute the query.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `ManagedAttribute` doesn't have a name field. It has `displayName`, so instead of `getObjectByName` use `context.search` using `queryOption` on the basis of `displayName`.